# Importance of order of elements in SOAP Header

Tags: visual-studio-2010, soap, wsdl

I imported a WSDL (file) in VS2010 for my project (a client Web Service in c#).

Class are correctly generated. I can catch (with Fiddler application) the SOAP message sent.
But actually the server is waiting a specific order in the Soap header, the reply is 400 HTTP error: The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax

Message sent:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Header>
                <h:Security xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <UsernameToken>
                        <Username>umwsuser</Username>
                        <Password>test</Password>
                    </UsernameToken>
                </h:Security>
                <h:AdditionalInfo xmlns:h="http://myserver/ws/common" xmlns="http://myserver/ws/common">
                    <ClientName>ISClient</ClientName>
                </h:AdditionalInfo>
        </s:Header>
        .....
    </s:Envelope>
```

Server is waiting "AdditionalInfo" first and "Security" after :

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Header>
                <h:AdditionalInfo xmlns:h="http://myserver/ws/common" xmlns="http://myserver/ws/common">
                    <ClientName>ISClient</ClientName>
                </h:AdditionalInfo>
                <h:Security xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <UsernameToken>
                        <Username>umwsuser</Username>
                        <Password>test</Password>
                    </UsernameToken>
                </h:Security>
        </s:Header>
        .....
    </s:Envelope>
```

I took the message that i sent to server, inversed Security element and AdditionalInfo element and then sent with SOAPUI application, the reply from server was Ok.

I tryed to inverse soap header element in WSDL file then generated again the class, it changed the class but the message is still sent with "Security" element in first.

From a point of view Server Web service does it mandatory to have element in a specific order? 
Why I can't change the order of element sent by the Client? (even I changed order of element in WSDL file)

A part of WSDL content:

```
    <operation name="Getdata">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Getdata"/>
        <input>
            <soap:header message="tns:AdditionalInfo" part="AdditionalInfo" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:SecurityHeader" part="Security" use="literal"/>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:IDResponse" part="IDResponse" use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
```

Comment: Can you show us the parts of the WSDL that pertain to the header?

Comment: Also, how did you import the WSDL? "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Yes I used "Add Service reference".

Comment: I added the part of Header in initial message